# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined from mongoDB update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

This one has me stumped..

Using the nodejs Mongodb driver I call an update function

```
 return this.collection.updateOne({_id: alertId}, {
        $set: set,
    })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('here');
        });
```

I have a breakpoint right before the 'return' and then again after the 'then'.  I never hit the 'then' breakpoint.

Then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I use this update function all the time.. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: i mean... obviously it's not returning a promise. Does your actual code have a callback that you left out here?

Comment: Assuming `this.collection` is a native driver collection object, that code looks fine, aside from the stray trailing comma after `set`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [$set a field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/).

```
return this.collection.updateOne(

   {_id: alertId},

   {
       $set: {<fieldName>: <value>}   <-- Need a key/value pair here.
   })

   .then((data) => {
        console.log('here');
   });
```

Comment: But you do not specify **which** field and what it's value is.  Look again.

Comment: Oh sorry.. my set is an object like that.
it looks like this
const set = {
    closedAt: new Date()
};

Comment: You need a key/value **pair**.

Comment: I wouldn't name a field "set" under any circumstance, but anyway, if you want to keep that name, it's like this:  $set: {set: set}.

Comment: Tried that.. Same error. Thanks for all the help though.

Comment: @JeffMatthews `set` in the OP's example _is_ a key/value pair (JS object). I think you're off in the weeds here.

Comment: I removed my previous answer bc I was looking at the wrong docs. I would recommend trying your query in Robo3T or another GUI. I suspect something is wrong with the query. Maybe getting working in GUI first...

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.. I was chaining a bunch of promises to filter back down.  Somewhere I had a loop that wasn't returning a promise from every option.  It's just weird the error manifested itself here at the collection.update method.